# Deserialising XML doc throwing errors - how to find out where it is failing

Tags: c#, xml, ofx

I am trying to deserialize an OFX xml document into its object (I converted the XSD's to classes)

Here is the code below.

```
  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OFX));

        using (var reader = xmlDoc.Root.CreateReader())
        {
            return (OFXRequest)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```

It fails on newing up of the xml XmlSerializer with the error

The xml doc:

```
<?OFX OFXHEADER=200  VERSION=211  SECURITY="NONE"  OLDFILEUID="NONE"  NEWFILEUID="NONE"  ?>
<OFX>
  <SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
    <SONRQ>
      <DTCLIENT>20120202</DTCLIENT>
      <USERID>USER-ID</USERID>
      <USERPASS>PASSWORD</USERPASS>
      <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
      <FI>
        <ORG>Organisation</ORG>
        <FID>OrganisationID</FID>
      </FI>
      <APPID>YOD</APPID>
      <APPVER>1</APPVER>
    </SONRQ>
  </SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
  <SIGNUPMSGSRQV1>
    <ACCTINFOTRNRQ>
      <TRNUID>456579841231</TRNUID>
      <ACCTINFORQ>
        <DTACCTUP>2013101209000.000[2:GMT]</DTACCTUP>
      </ACCTINFORQ>
    </ACCTINFOTRNRQ>
  </SIGNUPMSGSRQV1>
</OFX>
```

The Error:

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030: Cannot
>   convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string' error CS0030: Cannot
>   convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string' error CS0030: Cannot
>   convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

What I need do know is how do I find the exact place in code that is failing whilst deserializing? There is no inner exception etc.

Comment: What is your OFXRequest class looks like?

Comment: This error is during the meta-data/meta-programming phase - not the "read the xml" phase - consequently the interesting thing here is not the xml, but rather: the c#. What does `OFXRequest` look like?

Comment: Its about 50000 lines long - a bit difficult to paste here. I could upload the files to a server somewhere?

Comment: So what I suspect happens is in the Constructor of the `XOFRequest` your assigning a `DateTime` to a `String`. Remember to use the syntax `stringVar = dateTimeVar.ToString();` rather than `stringVar = dateTimeVar;` otherwise you'll get a casting error complaining it cant convert...

Comment: The odd thing is - all the dates in the classes are set as strings - not datetime - I am very confused as to why I am getting that error :(

Comment: You are not making it easy :). My guess is that your OFXRequest's DTACCTUP property or DTCLIENT property, or both are strings, while they are mapped to DateTime. However, is's hard to tell without looking at the code, and analyzing the whole bunch of files you've provided is a little bit over the head.

Comment: Agreed - there is about 100k+ lines of code. Its a nightmare. The specific class I am looking at is Datafeed.Contracts.OFX2Protocol.cs

Comment: Nope, OFXRequest class is not there...

Comment: Sorry - changed it to the OFX class - will edit code on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, it is confused what you want it do do with things like this

```
[XmlElement(Type=typeof(string),ElementName="TAXYEAR",IsNullable=false,DataType="gYear")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public TAXYEARCollection __TAXYEARCollection;
```

which clearly says "treat the values as a string", verses this:

```
[Serializable]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public class TAXYEARCollection : ArrayList
{
    public DateTime Add(DateTime obj)
    {
        base.Add(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public DateTime Add()
    {
        return Add(new DateTime());
    }

    public void Insert(int index, DateTime obj)
    {
        base.Insert(index, obj);
    }

    public void Remove(DateTime obj)
    {
        base.Remove(obj);
    }

    new public DateTime this[int index]
    {
        get { return (DateTime) base[index]; }
        set { base[index] = value; }
    }
}
```

which clearly wants values to be a `DateTime`.

Comment: Ive changed [XmlElement(Type=typeof(string),ElementName="TAXYEAR",IsNullable=false,DataType="gYear")] to [XmlElement(Type=typeof(DateTime),ElementName="TAXYEAR",IsNullable=false,DataType="gYear")] and I am now receiving a slightly better error.. 'gYear' is an invalid value for the XmlElementAttribute.DataType property. gYear cannot be converted to System.DateTime.

Comment: Hacked the generated classes to replace gyear with type string and datetime with type string. now it deserialises beautifully. Thanks Marc Gravell for you insight.